# Півдороги чи пів дороги?

Tags: орфографія, разом-дефіс-окремо

Добрий день!
Новий правопис каже:

> Невідмінюваний числівник пів зі значенням ‘половина’ з наступним
> іменником — загальною та власною назвою у формі родового відмінка
> однини пишемо окремо: пів áркуша, пів відрá, пів годúни, пів лі́тра...
> Якщо ж пів з наступним іменником у формі називного відмінка становить
> єдине поняття і не виражає значення половини, то їх пишемо разом:
> півáркуш, пíвдень, півзáхист, півкóло, півкýля, півлі́тра (розм.
> ‘пляшка з горілкою або іншою випивкою ємністю 0,5 літра’), півмі́сяць,
> півóберт, півовáл, півóстрів.

СУМ [подає](http://sum.in.ua/s/pivdorogha) півдорогу так:

> ПІВДОРО́ГА, и, жін. Середина віддалі між чим-небудь. Я несу кошик,..
> ступаю в калошах. Минає так.. з півгодини. Могли б вже бути на
> півдорозі (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 235); Він.. почав вертатися
> з півдороги, аби не спіткати людей (Любов Яновська, I, 1959, 313); //
> перен. Середина якого-небудь процесу, дії і т. ін.

Тобто в контексті, наприклад, "Я вмикаю музику в телефоні на півдорозі через місто, що розкинулось..." - "півдорога" постає як раз у значенні "середина", а не буквально "половина чогось".

Тож як тут бути - разом чи окремо?)
Щиро дякую завчасно)

Comment: ТРЕНАЖЕР З ПРАВОПИСУ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ
https://webpen.com.ua/pages/Morphology_and_spelling/orthography_words_with_piv-poly.html

Answer (score 3):

Дякуємо за ретельно досліджене запитання. Власне кажучи, наведених вами джерел цілком достатньо, щоб відповісти на нього.

Єдине, що треба зробити, це зрозуміти контекст, в якому це слово вживається у конкретний момент, а також спробувати замінити слово синонімом і подивитися, чи не втрачається сенс.

*«Увімкнув музику на **півдорозі**»* — тут значення «середина», а не «половина». Речення можна без втрати сенсу замінити на *«увімкнув музику на **середині** дороги»*.

*«Ваша бригада ремонтує **пів дороги**, а наша — інші **пів {дороги}**»* — тут значення саме «половина». Замінити на *«середину»* неможливо, але натомість можна замінити на *«ремонтуємо **частину** дороги»*.

Comment: @stegetsj, не зрозумів, навіщо замінювати стандартне SE форматування на нестандартне HTML-ове. У вас ця сторінка не показується правильно? Чи SE Знову анонсували якісь breaking changes? (вони на це здатні)

Comment: @stegetsj, цікаво. Може, залежить від браузера/платформи. У мене Firefox 80 linux/windows, все нормально показувало з самого початку (інакше б виправив одразу). Гаразд, най буде так, як ви зробили, просто все розлетиться, якщо SE, наприклад, прибере підтримку HTML-теґів; з них станеться. :)

Comment: Дякую, але для мене відповідь не очевидна (у світлі змін у правописі), тому й питаю))